# assinging "-n" string to a variable doesn't work

Tags: bash

```
$ OPTION="-n"
$ echo $OPTION
$
```

Nothing happens. I expected this.

```
$ OPTION="-n"
$ echo $OPTION
-n
$
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

`-n` is a parameter to echo, which means the trailing newline is suppressed. The fact that there's no empty line between `$ echo $OPTION` and the following `$` means that $OPTION is properly set to `-n`.

If you put something else in front of $OPTION, the echo will work as you expect it to. `echo` only interprets words at the beginning of the command as options. As soon as it finds a non-option word ("OPTION", in this case), all words that follow are treated as literals, and not parsed as options to `echo`.

```
$ echo OPTION is set to $OPTION
OPTION is set to -n
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the shell expands environment variables before the command is executed. Thus:

```
option="-n"
echo $option
```

becomes

```
echo -n ""
```

With the value of `$option` being interpreted as a parameter for the `echo` command. If you were using Kornshell (which is 95% similar to BASH), you could have used the builtin `print` command instead:

```
option="-n"
print -- "$option"
```

Unfortunately, BASH doesn't have the print command, and using the double dash in the BASH echo command will print out a double dash -- not what you want.

Instead, you'll have to use the `printf` command which is a bit slower than `echo`:

```
option="-n"
printf -- "$option\n"  #Must include the \n to make a new line!
```

Of course, if you had this, you'd be in trouble:

```
option="%d"
printf -- "$option\n"
```

To get around that:

```
option="%d"
printf "%s\n", "$option"
```

By the way, you have the same problems with test:

```
option="-n"
if [ "$option" -eq "-n" ]   #Won't work!
```

This is why you'll see people do this:

if [ "x$option" -eq "x-n" ]  #Will work

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result, you could do this:

```
$ OUTPUT='-n'
$ echo -en ${OUTPUT}\\n
```